# R how to determinate the position of each element in two columns using the position of a list

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a data frame with 2 columns

```
groups
                   g1                 g2
1                Soil              Feces
2                Soil               Skin
3                Soil             Tongue
4                Soil         Freshwater
6                Soil              Ocean
8                Soil               Mock
11              Feces         Freshwater
12              Feces Freshwater (creek)
14              Feces Sediment (estuary)
18               Skin Freshwater (creek)
23             Tongue Freshwater (creek)
27         Freshwater Freshwater (creek)
31 Freshwater (creek)              Ocean
33 Freshwater (creek)               Mock
```

So I want to add 2 extra columns based in the position of the all elements of g1 and g2 columns, if we extract a single elements based in the g1 and g2 columns

```
l <- union(unique(g$g1), unique(g$g2))

[1] "Soil"  "Feces" "Skin" "Tongue" "Freshwater" "Freshwater (creek)" "Ocean" "Mock" "Sediment (estuary)"
```

So the position of Soil in l correspond to 1, Faces to 2 and so on:

```
Soil               : 1
Feces              : 2
Skin               : 3
Tongue             : 4
Freshwater         : 5
Freshwater (creek) : 6
Ocean              : 7
Mock               : 8
Sediment (estuary) : 9
```

So I want to add the position bases in the g1 and g2 in 2 extra columns, if Soil correspond to 1 and Feces to 2, so xg1 and xg2 will be to 1 and 2, something like:

```
   groups
                       g1                 g2       xg1         xg2
    1                Soil              Feces        1          2
    2                Soil               Skin        1          3
    3                Soil             Tongue        1          4
    4                Soil         Freshwater        1          5
    6                Soil              Ocean        1          7         
    8                Soil               Mock        1          8
    11              Feces         Freshwater        2          5
    12              Feces Freshwater (creek)        2          6
    14              Feces Sediment (estuary)        2          9
    18               Skin Freshwater (creek)        3          6
    23             Tongue Freshwater (creek)        4          6
    27         Freshwater Freshwater (creek)        5          6
    31 Freshwater (creek)              Ocean        6          7
    33 Freshwater (creek)               Mock        6          8
```

I have tried a loop with the list (l) and the command which, but I just can't make it

Thanks So Much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

```
library(tidyverse)

# creating a key
key <- structure(list(V1 = c("Soil", "Feces", "Skin", "Tongue", "Freshwater", 
"Freshwater (creek)", "Ocean", "Mock", "Sediment (estuary)"), 
    V2 = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9")), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L), class = "data.frame")

df %>%
  mutate(
    xg1 = key$V2[match(df$g1, key$V1)],
    xg2 = key$V2[match(df$g2, key$V1)]
    )
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(g1 = c("Soil", "Soil", "Soil", "Soil", "Soil", 
"Soil", "Feces", "Feces", "Feces", "Skin", "Tongue", "Freshwater", 
"Freshwater (creek)", "Freshwater (creek)"), g2 = c("Feces", 
"Skin", "Tongue", "Freshwater", "Ocean", "Mock", "Freshwater", 
"Freshwater (creek)", "Sediment (estuary)", "Freshwater (creek)", 
"Freshwater (creek)", "Freshwater (creek)", "Ocean", "Mock")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-14L))
```